# Setting up Scrolling to place textbox in field programmatically

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

For an iPhone app with users entering their data into text boxes,

I need the page to scroll both when the text boxes are selected for user to input and when keyboard has not been opened for user to review what they entered.

When using the Interface Builder and overlaying the scroll view, I can't get it to stay or save so that the page is actually scrollable.

I would also prefer to do this programmatically. Other solutions like this have not worked when inserted into the .m file.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *topScrollView;
@synthesize topScrollView;

[topScrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 65)];
[topScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(500, 100)];
[topScrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[topScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[topScrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:YES];
[topScrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
[[self view] addSubview:topScrollView];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place a UIView with all your textfields on top of the main view and set NSNotifications for the keyboard and move the view around accordingly.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShowWithNotification:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHideWithNotification:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

#pragma mark NSNotifications
- (void)keyboardDidShowWithNotification:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    const int movementDistance = ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568 ? 155 : 180);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut|UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                 animations:^{
                     CGPoint adjust = CGPointMake(0, -movementDistance);
                     CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(self.loginContainer.center.x+adjust.x, self.loginContainer.center.y+adjust.y);
                     [self.loginContainer setCenter:newCenter];
                 }
                 completion:nil];
}
- (void)keyboardDidHideWithNotification:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut|UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                 animations:^{
                     self.loginContainer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.loginContainer.frame.size.width, self.loginContainer.frame.size.height);
                 }
                 completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Could you expand or add code to state what a loginContainer is or what it does here?

Comment: LoginContainer is a UIView with all my subviews on it, once the keyboard opens up I move my logincontainer up and once the user finishes and keyboard closes, I move the logincontainer back down.